# Website non-responsive while streaming mp4

Tags: php, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm streaming large (500mb+) mp4 files, using a function found [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices).
The idea is to keep the video source hidden, and thus far it's working.

The only issue is that interacting with the site (clicking a link, etc.) is not possible until the the video has completed - even if you pause it. Also you pretty much have to close the tab and/or browser to get the website to respond. It appears that it's possible to make requests on another browser, so I know that the server itself isn't locked.

Here's the function:

```
$file = "/home/webtest/videos/720p/video.mp4"; // The media file's location     
    $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');

    $size   = filesize($file); // File size
    $length = $size;           // Content length
    $start  = 0;               // Start byte
    $end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
    $content_type = 'application/octet-stream'; // type

    header('Content-Type: '.$content_type);
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end   = $end;
        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false){
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-'){
            $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
        } else {
            $range  = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size){
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }

        $start  = $c_start;
        $end    = $c_end;
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
        fseek($fp, $start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }

    // Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: $length");

    // Start buffered download
    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end){
        if ($p + $buffer > $end){
            $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
        }

        set_time_limit(0);
        echo fread($fp, $buffer);
        flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Here's the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 23:36:59 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: 0-203395220
Content-Range: bytes 0-203395219/203395220
Content-Length: 203395220
Connection: close
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=24mf06f150895og6s59b9nfte5
DNT:1
Host:
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36
```

If you think this method is incorrect or flawed, I'm definitely open to alternative methods for streaming. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request in which you're serving the download is keeping the session file locked, so subsequent requests will block until they can acquire the lock themselves.

All you need to do is toss in the following at some point between being finished with `$_SESSION` and your `fread()` loop:

```
session_write_close();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that

Comment: Life. Saver. Thank you!